# Regex to match url format

Tags: java, pattern-matching

Regex to match url in this format xy12.example.com/abc?param1=dasdasd4234234

Comment: Yes, it can be done with regex. Now is a great time for you to **learn regex**, so you can write the regex pattern needed for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with this regular expression

```
^https://xy0?[2-5]?.*
```

- ^https://xy means that you expect that the input string starts with the string 'https://xy'
- 0? means that the 0 is optional (so the string will match if it is present or not)
- [2-5]? means that it can contain a number from 2 to 5 optionally
- .* means that after the pattern the string could contain any other character

For example

```
String pattern = "^https://xy0?[2-5]?.*";

System.out.println("https://xy02.example.com/abc ".matches(pattern));
```